# unable to end call in android verstion 2.2.6

Tags: android, telephonymanager, getmethod

i trying to end call using below method to e

```
private void getTeleService(Context context) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    try {

        Class c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
        m.setAccessible(true);
        com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
        telephonyService.silenceRinger();
        telephonyService.endCall();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("","FATAL ERROR: could not connect to telephony subsystem");
        Log.e("", "Exception object: " + e);
    }
}
```

this working fine with android version 2.2 but unable to end call in android version 2.2.6
i don't know what wrong in this code.

i got the solution i just comment out this line telephonyService.silenceRinger();
 because this method is not support above android  2.3 version

please help me 
thanks in adv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android was changed after 2.2, these tricks non longer work