# How to stop a call in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, phone-call

I can make a call with android using below code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "01234567"));
startActivity(intent);
```

But how to stop the call after some time?

Comment: Take a look at there 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10671510/how-to-stop-a-intent-action-call-once-started

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this:
[PhoneCallHandlingAndroidProject](https://github.com/angtwr31/phonehandlingdemo)

Method `disconnectCall()` disconnect the call used in MainActivity.